# Unable to create rdd from another rdd

Tags: pyspark

**Can anybody help?**

I am using PySpark on Jupyter Notebook. I want to create an RDD from another RDD.

```
dataRDD = sc.parallelize("welcome to pySpark by brightrace academy".split(" ")) 
newDataRDD = dataRDD.map(lambda line: line.upper())
newDataRDD.collect()
```

I get an error when I try to create an RDD from an existing RDD:

**The error:**

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-de8c35a40e72> in <module>
      2 
      3 newDataRDD = dataRDD.map(lambda line: line.upper())
----> 4 newDataRDD.collect()

C:\SPARK\python\pyspark\rdd.py in collect(self)
```

Comment: The full error message:

Comment: A very long py4JJavaError message

Comment: I have executed the same on my env and it is working. Can you please provide more details? Result: ['WELCOME', 'TO', 'PYSPARK', 'BY', 'BRIGHTRACE', 'ACADEMY']

Comment: Thanks Alex for being the first one to reply. I executed the same code on my laptop and it works but not on the desktop, Is that possibly an Anaconda issue? Do I need to uninstall and install Anaconda  on my desktop again? The error message is too long like: It's a very long error message:

Comment: Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 4.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 16, 10.0.0.239, executor driver): java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/opt/conda/bin/python": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
 at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1128)
 at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1071)